# Saving json response in create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to save a json response but it is saving the title instead of the value.  Also having issues with how the params are coming through with slashes instead of as a hash

I have the following response from form submit:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"2134", "shipping_rate"=>{..."shipping_rate"=>"{\"serviceName\"=>\"USPS First Class Mail - Package\", \"serviceCode\"=>\"usps_first_class_mail\", \"shipmentCost\"=>2.66, \"otherCost\"=>0.0}"}, "commit"=>"Create Shipping rate"}
```

**form:**

```
...
<% @rates.each do |rate| %>
  <%= form.radio_button :shipping_rate, rate.as_json %> <%= rate %><br />
<% end %>
...
```

I am under the impression using `as_json` removes the "/" so it comes through as a hash parameters.

I also tried using `@rates.as_json.each` with same results

**Create** method in controller:

```
@shipping_rate.service_code = params["shipping_rate"]["shipping_rate"]["serviceCode"]
```

How the service_code saves is as "serviceCode" and not "usps_first_class_mail".

How can I:

1. Have the params come through as a hash, without the `/`'s
2. Save the value of `params["shipping_rate"]["shipping_rate"]["serviceCode"]` instead of the title

Answer (score 0):

`rate.as_json` is correctly returning a hash, but when you pass data to form.radio_button it get's converted into something html friendly. Basically, form.radio_button calls `.to_s` (or some similar method that probably also escapes html) on that hash, which is why you're getting the hash as a string.

As a rule, individual HTML form elements should not contain hash data, and especially not ruby formatted hash data. Keep in mind that once the page is rendered in a browser, it knows nothing about the backend, let alone how to run ruby code.

You should take a step back and think of this RESTfully. If your users are meant to select a rate, and you have a number of rate records in your db, you really only need them to send back the *id* of the rate they would like. Without seeing your controller it's hard to tell exactly what else would need to change, but your radio buttons should probably look more like:

```
<%= form.radio_button :rate_id, rate.id %>
```

Your controller's create method would then be responsible for setting the user's selected rate, possibly requiring you to look up the rate again.

Comment: The @rates is from an API so the response is json.  Sorry, should have explained that...  I am looking for a hash, but wondering why the way I "save" the `["serviceCode"]`, it saves the title and not the value from the parameters... and what's up with the `/`'s in the parameters and how I can rid them... I read that using `as_json` would do that but somehow doenst?

Comment: As I said, as_json _does_ correctly return a hash. The issue is that you're trying to put that hash into a radio button. That simply will not work. As a form element, radio buttons expect simple data (really just strings) and if you try to render one with a hash it will coerce that hash into a string. That's where the \s are coming from. I can really only recommend that you find another way to do this. You cannot get hash data into a single radio button without a lot of shoehorning, and you almost certainly should not do so. If you're really set on doing this, you can try `.to_json` instead